# How to remove everything except specific set of characters/word using regex on vscode?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a very huge dump which i downloaded from imdb and here's a tiny example from the dump.

```
   nm0000006    Ingrid Bergman  1915    1982    actress,soundtrack,producer tt0036855,tt0077711,tt0038109,tt0034583
    nm0000007   Humphrey Bogart 1899    1957    actor,soundtrack,producer   tt0033870,tt0034583,tt0037382,tt0043265
    nm0000008   Marlon Brando   1924    2004    actor,soundtrack,director   tt0078788
    nm0000009   Richard Burton  1925    1984    actor,soundtrack,producer   tt0061184,tt0059749,tt0057877,tt0087803
    nm0000010   James Cagney    1899    1986    actor,soundtrack,director   tt0031867,tt0042041
```

Those "tt0029870" are the only things i need.

**How should i do it on regex so everything so i can remove everything except** those tt0031867 type codes?

I need the dump to look like this: `tt0036855tt0077711tt0038109tt0034583tt0036855tt0077711tt0038109tt0034583tt0036855tt0077711tt0038109tt0034583`

I will use vs code to find & replace/remove it using regex.

Answer (score 0):

It obviously depends on the regex flavor you use.

[Here is a solution](https://regex101.com/r/0XDuWO/1).

The regex is `.*?(tt\d+)`:

- `.*` will match any number of any characters, but the `?` modifiers tells it to match as few as possible;
- `(` and `)` capture some matched text, the one we want to preserve in the substitution;
- `tt` matches literal `tt`;
- `\d` matches a digit, but `+` tells it to match 1 or more (and, without `?`, it matches as *many* as possible).

The modifiers applied to the regex are `g` to repeat the matching over and over on the lines, and `s` to make `.` match the newline character too.

Comment: Hi there, im trying to replace/remove the undesired codes on a plain file not through php or some sort. I tried using the regex code on vscode & notepad++ and 0 result found.,

Comment: @Amenadiel Enlico forgot to tell that you have to set the replace to `$1` and you have to delete the newlines with a search for `\n`

Comment: @rioV8 true the first (I'll fix later), false the second. See the last paragraph.

Comment: in VSC you can't set all the flags, `s` is not a possible option in the find GUI box

Comment: In vscode you have to handle newlines explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in a few steps:

1. Remove all of the line up to the first `tt0123456`
   search: `^.*?(?=tt\d{7})`
   replace: empty
2. Remove all `,`
   search: `,`
   replace: empty
3. Remove all newlines
   search: `\n`
   replace: empty

Answer (score 0):

Find: `(\btt\d+\b)|\n|.`

Replace: `$`

Just this one operation is sufficient.  Tested in vscode.

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RtAlXU/1)

Frequently an alternation of what you want and don't want is the easiest way.  Order of the alternates is **important**.  Generally put what you want first and match the other stuff afterwards.

Find: `(tt\d+)|[\s\S]*?` also works but might be a more expensive operation.

Answer (score -2):

/tt0029870/ Will Work in your case.
In DB you can always use Like

Select * from *YOURTABE* where code like '%tt0029870%'

Comment: Hi there, i don't want to use the tsv dump or import it to my database. I want to store the ids on a file just for checking purposes.

Comment: have you tried this /tt0029870/ ?

If you are using vs code use Command D to find next occurrence and then you'll be able to edit them all at once.